# Formula if cell = value to carry out formula else...Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to modify the code below to check for a string, `---`.  If the string exist, then return the value 9999, else carry out formula:

`.Formula = "=IF(" & strLowLimCol & "2" = ""---"," & _
                strMeasCol & "2-" & strLowLimCol & "2," & _
                9999)"`

Can you tell me where my error is?

Here is the full code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReturnMarginal()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLowLimCol As Long, strLowLimCol As String
    Dim lngHiLimCol As Long, strHiLimCol As String
    Dim lngMeasCol As Long, strMeasCol As String
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

    ' get worksheetfunction references
    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    ' iterate worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' validate LowLimit label is on sheet
        If Not (ws.Rows(1).Find("LowLimit") Is Nothing) Then

        ' get location of input data columns and number of rows
        lngLowLimCol = wsf.Match("LowLimit", ws.Rows(1), 0)
        lngHiLimCol = wsf.Match("HighLimit", ws.Rows(1), 0)
        lngMeasCol = wsf.Match("MeasValue", ws.Rows(1), 0)
        lngLastRow = ws.Cells(1, lngLowLimCol).End(xlDown).Row

        ' get column letters for input data columns
        strLowLimCol = Split(ws.Cells(1, lngLowLimCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        strHiLimCol = Split(ws.Cells(1, lngHiLimCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        strMeasCol = Split(ws.Cells(1, lngMeasCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

        ' output headers
        ws.Range("P1") = "Meas-LO"
        ws.Range("Q1") = "Meas-Hi"
        ws.Range("R1") = "Min Value"
        ws.Range("S1") = "Marginal"

        ' assign formulas to outputs
        ' Meas-LO
        'Range("P2:P" & lngLastRow).Select
        '    With Selection
        '        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        '        .Value = .Value
        '    End With
        With ws.Range("P2:P" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=IF(" & strLowLimCol & "2" = ""---"," & 
                strMeasCol & "2-" & strLowLimCol & "2," & _
                9999)"

        End With

        ' Meas-Hi
        With ws.Range("Q2:Q" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(" & strHiLimCol & "2)," & _
                strMeasCol & "2-" & strHiLimCol & "2," & _
                9999 & "2)"
                'strMeasCol & "2)"
        End With

        ' Min Value
        With ws.Range("R2:R" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=MIN(P2,Q2)"
        End With

        ' Marginal
        With ws.Range("S2:S" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=IF(AND(R2>=-3,R2<=3),""Marginal"",R2)"
        End With
        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing a `"` at the beginning of `9999)"`  It should be `"9999)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few erroneous "", I think your line should be:

```
.Formula = "=IF(" & strLowLimCol & "2 = ""---""," & _
strMeasCol & "2-" & strLowLimCol & "2, 9999)"
```

So the final output would be (if strLowLimCol was "B" and strMeasCol was "C")

IF(B2="---",C2-B2,9999)